# Download PDF after CF7 form submission

Tags: php, functions, advanced-custom-fields, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm working on a client's build, and I'd like to change as little as possible. I'm not too familiar with all this, my apologies - I'll try to show where I'm at.

The client wants a form submission to prompt a PDF download. There are two different PDFs, two instances of the same form. Fill out form instance 1, get PDF A - Form instance 2, PDF B.

Here's how those instances show up:

```
<div id="whitepaper" class="home_whitepaper_bg w-clearfix">
  <?php $lpcnt=0; if(have_rows('whitepaper_list')): ?>
  <?php while(have_rows('whitepaper_list')): the_row(); $lpcnt++; ?>
<!-- Making rows for content, looping through and counting loops = lpcnt -->

<!--
... Other content ...
-->

  <?php 
   the_sub_field('whitepaper_download_form'); 
  ?>
  <?php
   $pdf=get_permalink().'?download='.get_sub_field('whitepaper_pdf');
  ?>
  <a data-fancybox data-src="#whitepaper_popup_<?php echo $lpcnt; ?>" data-redirect="<?php echo $pdf; ?>" href="javascript:;" class="whitepaper_download_link w-inline-block w-clearfix">
<!-- Here's the buttons for fancybox popups. They use the loop count to build a specific url - this is info I want later! -->
```

And in the popup window:

```
    <div id="whitepaper_popup_<?php echo $lpcnt; ?>" class="whitepaper_popup">
<!-- using that loop count to get a specific div id! -->
        <div class="popup_whitepaper">
            <div class="whitepaper_form">
                <!-- 
I could put a <?php echo do_shortcode...> here, no? 
Their current solution is to grab a javascript code from an ACF field. 
I have had a lot of trouble figuring out how to put the CF7 form in that field.
                -->
                <?php the_sub_field('download_form'); ?>
                <div class="w-clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <button data-fancybox-close="" class="fancybox-close-small"></button>
            <div class="w-clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Right. So there's that. Then, using CF7's new DOM events, I should be able to setup a redirect or simliar?

in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
if ( 'FORM ID' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
    location = <!-- specific url derived from $lpcnt? -->;
}
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not - also, can't figure out exactly how I can get the right URL into my wpcf7mailsent event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need much code for it. just goto contact form > select contact form > additional setting, paste below code.
`document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
location = 'YOUR_PDF_URL';}, false );`

Comment: That would work - though I'm looking to have one form serve two different files, depending on where the user accesses the form. If I can get the PDF URL to be built outside of the event listener, and refer to that variable there - perfect!

Comment: I think I'm just going to end up doing this. I won't programmatically differentiate between downloads, and just make two forms with two different downloads. For now, at least. Thanks, @parths .

Comment: Can we make that pdf open in new tab, instead of same tab ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the need to add a download CTA after the content of all case studies of a website, but "in exchange" of user's data for:

- display a CF7 form on your page, I had the same one on all case studies post type single which I hooked after the content
- find a way to get the wanted PDF url for people to download, as for me all case studies have a different PDF, I simply added an ACF field, filtered on PDF only, which returns the file url
- based on [CF7 Dom events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/), choose the action you prefer to make the dowload happens, as I am not sending any confirmation email, I prefer working on the wpcf7submit event. Note that wpcf7submit event is fired only if the form has been validated

So the code looks like this:

```
<?php 
// For simplicity, using an anonymous functions
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', function () {
    // Check the wanted singular post type loading
    if ( is_admin() || ! is_singular( 'case-study' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the ACF PDF field is not empty for use
    $pdf_link = get_field( 'pdf' );
    if ( empty( $pdf_link ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Hook on the "wpcf7submit" CF7 Dom event to force the download
    printf( "<script>document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) { window.open('%s'); }, false );</script>", $pdf_link );
} );
```

Comment: @just-jeff I know this is time ago, but it could still be a need

Comment: Yes, I needed 2 weeks ago, and after a lot of research none questions was correctly answered. So could you consider upvoting in order people to find the right answer to this question please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin:

1. Download the plugin
2. Install
3. Set the form id and PDF attachment under CF7 file download settings.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-file-download/